# How to create dictionaries (key, value) pair in r?

Tags: r

I want to create dictionary(key, value(lists)) pair in r. and want to loop through lists in r as we do in python like below. i got to know something like hashes i tried it but didn't work exactly.

```
ex in python:
------------
thisdict = {
  "brand": ['a','b','c'],
  "model": ['1-10','2-20','3-30'],
  "KK": [1,2,3,4]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list structure is a hash table in R.

```
thisdict <-list(
brand = letters[1:3],
model = c('1-10','2-20','3-30'),
KK = 1:4
)
```

You receive values either with double square `[[` bracket or `$`:

```
thisdict[['brand']]
thisdict$brand
```